# Output operator (<<) for abstract class and derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I have 2 classes, a abstract base class & derived class.
But for some reason i cannot properly overload the output operators for both.

Here is the base class:

```
class team
{
    char* team_name;
    int games_played;

public:
    team(const char* tname);
    virtual ~team();
    virtual void update_lpoints(const int win_loss)=0;
    friend std:: ostream& operator<< (std :: ostream& out, team& T);    
};

std:: ostream& operator<< (std :: ostream& out, team& T);
```

And here is the output operator:

```
std:: ostream& operator<< (std :: ostream& out, team& T)
{
    return (out<<T.team_name<<" "<<T.games_played);
}
```

The derived class:

```
class BasketTeam : public team
{
    int league_points;
    int points_for;
    int points_against;

public:
        BasketTeam(const char* tname);  
        ~BasketTeam();

        friend std:: ostream& operator<< (std :: ostream& out, BasketTeam& T);  
};

std:: ostream& operator<< (std :: ostream& out, BasketTeam& T);
```

Here is the output operator for the derived class:

```
std:: ostream& operator<< (std :: ostream& out, BasketTeam& T)
{
    out<<T.get_name()<<"    "<<T.get_played_games()<<"  "<<T.league_points<<"   "<<T.points_for<<"  "<<T.points_against<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

When I create the object and try to print it i can only get the base class to appear not the derived class.

```
team* tt = new BasketTeam ("ran");
cout<<*tt;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overloaded `operator <<` is selected on compile time, based on the static types of the arguments. Since `tt`'s static type is `team`, that's the `operator <<` that it used.

If you want the dynamic type of the object to determine the output, you have to use some other technique. For instance, you can have `team` contain a virtual `print` function, and override it in `BasketTeam`. Then, have one `operator <<` take a `team& t`, and call `t.print()` or so. This will invoke the `print` method according to the dynamic type of `t`, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! 
But there is one more issue, the output should be:
team_name 0 0 0 0 

but for some reason the output is:
team_name 00F9AC3E8 0 0 0 

any idea why ?
the variable is int and is initialized:
games_played=0;

But the address is the one being outputted.

Comment: The print header is:
std:: ostream& print_info(std :: ostream& out)

Comment: I can't say without seeing the relevant code. Could you possibly be doing something like `T.get_played_games`, omitting the Parentheses, which yields the function address instead of its returned value?

Comment: This is what i am doing:
(out<<team_name<<games_played)